# My react app on azure VM does not come up

Tags: node.js, azure

I have a react.app which I have uploaded the codes to an Azure VM machine on my public subnet. There is no issue with my network and for the purposes of development I have freed all port on security groups an giving them to have no restriction on inbound and outboundport. I have also a load balance which direct the traffic through public subnet. In my load balancer, I have inbound rules to forward for ports 22, and 3000 to the backend pool and VM machine having the react codes. I still can not access my website when I use my public IP of loadbalance along with the port 3000.

The app started on VM but I can not access when in my browser on my PC, I use the
20.*.*.92:3000

```
[root@****i]# npm start
> material-kit-pro-react@1.9.0 start /var/tmp/thermo-api
> http-server ./app -a 0.0.0.0 -p 3000 -c-1

Starting up http-server, serving ./app
Available on:
  http://127.0.0.1:3000
  http://10.0.1.4:3000
Hit CTRL-C to stop the server
```

Any clue or help would be appreciated!

EDIT

I can curl inside VM to port 3000 and it gets me to the webpage, but when I ssh to another node in VNET, I can still ping to the VM (10.0.1.4) but I can not curl to port 3000 of my VM.

```
[AzureUser@***** ~]$ ping 10.0.1.4
PING 10.0.1.4 (10.0.1.4) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.1.4: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.67 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.1.4: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=1.95 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.1.4: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=2.07 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.1.4: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=1.70 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.1.4: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=1.78 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.1.4: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=1.65 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.1.4: icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=1.78 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.1.4: icmp_seq=8 ttl=64 time=1.76 ms
^C
--- 10.0.1.4 ping statistics ---
8 packets transmitted, 8 received, 0% packet loss, time 19ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.645/1.794/2.069/0.142 ms
[AzureUser@**** ~]$ curl 10.0.1.4:3000
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.0.1.4 port 3000: No route to host
```

I have attached my iptables of the VM here

```
[root@****]# iptables -L -n -v
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 308K packets, 1658M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 DOCKER-USER  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 DOCKER     all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 !docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 307K packets, 55M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  docker0 !docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you're choosing to host a Javascript app on a virtual machine instead of in an app service?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, I am starting the app by npm start.

Comment: I'm saying that there are Azure services that allow you to host an application without setting up a dedicated virtual machine.

Comment: I know but for this I am hosting on my own VM.

Comment: And my question is "Why?"

Comment: This is my requirment and for simplicity..

Comment: It sounds like you're choosing the wrong tool for the job. If this were a carpentry site and you were asking a question about how to hammer nails with a wrench, it's reasonable to expect people to suggest that you use a hammer instead.

Comment: Do you have any sugesstion how to fix above error?

Comment: @DanielMann - not sure why you keep challenging the OP (or finding ways to diminish their choice of technology with analogies that seem out of place here). The reason for using a VM seems irrelevant. Also, unless they're using containers, they cannot listen on port 3000 with a Web App.

Comment: Could you show what's the configuration of your NAT or LB rules and health probe? Do you check if the port 3000 is open in the outbound of the local PC firewall? Can you try to `telnet` the port from your PC to verify the network connection?

Comment: hi, i can not telnet from my local PC to there as port 23 is closed.in my LB, I have inbound rules which map port 3000, 22, 23 to the same ports on VM, I have also put unrestricted inbound and outbound rules from anysource on my subnet security group (which  the VM located)

Comment: Is this issue fixed on your side?

Comment: Hi,actually i dont have any firewall when I run iptables, I always see alssources an destination have 0.0.0.0 address which I don't think they are restrcting access..I have also put the same inbound rule on my LB, but still I can not access my site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I have two points for you.

- Check if there is any firewall inside the Azure VM. Such as running [IPTables](https://www.tecmint.com/basic-guide-on-iptables-linux-firewall-tips-commands/) on Linux like `iptables -L -n -v`. Checking the status of IPTables / Firewall. Options “-L” (List ruleset), “-v” (Verbose) and “-n” (Displays in numeric format). You need to open the port 3000 in the VM firewall if there is.
- For your requirement, you may create an inbound NAT rule of the load balancer. It will look like this.
  [image]

You could follow this guide to [troubleshoot Azure Load Balancer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-troubleshoot). Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thnaks for your answer, disabling the iptables did the trick but can you explain to me why above iptables are restricting the connection?

Comment: Not sure, It seems that you are trying access across nodes on docker. There is a Chain FORWARD (policy DROP . The traffic flow should be a docker container eth0---VM NIC---docker0---host nic---host nic---docker0---VM NIC---docker container eth0

Comment: On Linux, Docker manipulates iptables rules to provide network isolation. https://docs.docker.com/network/iptables/